# pass two string variables to a jquery method while binding

Tags: jquery

this is the function which i need to call

```
function printExpectationReport(Interest, Influence) {}
```

A and B are two string variables, when i click it, console gives error as A and B not defined.

If any one has an idea how i should bind the  variables for the string. 
It will be much helpfull.

```
 TableData += "<div class='count-expectation'><a onclick='printExpectationReport("+A+","+B+") href='#'>" + arrayFound.length + "</div>";
```

Comment: why not attaching your jQuery in extra file and do it in a normal way? upd: oh, sorry, it may be done that way. But any way, why do not you attach your listener without intruding HTML tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
var a = 'something';
var b = 'something else';

$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    printExpectationReport(a, b);
});
```

Also keep in mind binding events on elements, which are dynamicly added to the document, should be done with `on()` syntax I've provided above.